# Laravel afterFind Callback Events

Tags: laravel

Is there any afterFind() Model Event in laravel as in cakePHP so that I can format the data after any search query. or any other way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Not that I know of. However, because Laravel uses real model object rather than arrays (does Cake still use arrays? I haven't used it in about 2 years) you don't really need to reformat the data. The model object itself can have methods to get what you want out of the raw data.

Comment: Looking for the exact same thing. I want to add additional data to items in a collection that’s used in multiple controllers, but Laravel’s making that difficult for me!

Answer (score 1):

It's not an event, but a mutator you can set in your model.  You simply create a method in your model named `setFooAttribute($value)` where `Foo` is the name of the column you want to modify in camelCase.

Example:

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

This is right from the documentation as seen here... http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Laravel model doesn't have an after find event.

But you can hook after find by using extension:https://packagist.org/packages/haegemon/lara-find-event