# Laravel before or after find event/hook

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm looking for the possibility to hook in the process of searching the records with laravel(Eloquent), that means not an action filter as `before` or `after` but something like Yii's `beforeFind` and `afterFind` that are launched respectively before DB search and after it. Spent some time browsing the docs but hadn't found a thing. Is there a solution for this? p.s.:I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711971/laravel-afterfind-callback-events) but I want to operate the collection of objects.

Comment: I'm curious, why exactly do you need this? You may find that there's a better way to do what it is that you need.

Comment: oh well, I need more general way to filter the output (and the related entities to it) regarding the user permissions/ regions and any other filter I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no such events, but you can easily create one in a Base Model:

```
class BaseModel extends \Eloquent {

    public static function find($id, $columns = array('*'))
    {

        Event::fire('before.find', array($this));

        $result = parent::find($id, $columns);

        Event::fire('after.find', array($this));

        return $result;

    }

}
```

Comment: `$this` is not available in a static context, so I have edited to make something a little more practical